# Does model formset not work with ajax?

Tags: django

views

```
    EventsFormSet =  modelformset_factory(Events, extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = EventsFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save(); 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sucess/')
   else:
       formset = EventsFormSet(queryset=Events.objects.filter(date__day=current_day, date__month=current_month, date__year = current_year))
   return render(request, template_name, {'formset': formset})
```

The above does not work. But this code works

```
    EventsFormSet =  modelformset_factory(Events, extra=0)
    formset = EventsFormSet(queryset=Events.objects.filter(date__day=current_day, date__month=current_month, date__year = current_year))
    return render(request, template_name, {'formset': formset})
```

P.S I am using ajax to update part of the webpage.

This is my jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".foo").click(function()
        {
            var day = $(this).text()
            day = day.substring(0, 2);
            $.post('/foo/',{day:day}, function(data) 

            {
                $("aside").hide().html(data).fadeIn("4000");
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you define "does not work" ? What exactly happens ?

Comment: I added my jquery.This is how it goes. When I used the code which I mentioned does not work, the part of the webpage which needs to get updated, does not get updated. But if I use the code which I mentioned which works, the part of the webpage get updated. So it has something to do with that. I hope that explains.

Comment: Also, if I just go to the page manually- without ajax fetching it dynamically, it works. I see all the forms listed. If I try to use to update part of the page, it does not get updated.

Comment: I used aside tag- <aside>. I don't think the issue is with that. As I mentioned, the code works if I am not requesting any submitted form data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having trouble with the POST part of this view, right? As other people have said, you should look at your browser console log and your django error log etc and post those messages as well so we get a clearer picture of what is wrong.

Did you configure your ajax posts to pass the CSRF token as well? See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)